# What are all those SQL operators in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I was looking through Laravel's source code and I've found a lot of SQL operators for Eloquent and I was wondering what are some of them and how can they be used.

I haven't managed to find any documentation unfortunately.

Here's the operators I've found in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php`:

```
protected $operators = [
    '=', '<', '>', '<=', '>=', '<>', '!=',
    'like', 'like binary', 'not like', 'between', 'ilike',
    '&', '|', '^', '<<', '>>',
    'rlike', 'regexp', 'not regexp',
    '~', '~*', '!~', '!~*', 'similar to',
    'not similar to',
];
```

And there's a bunch of them I don't understand. For example: `&`, `|`, `^`, `<<`, `>>`, `~`, `~*`, `!~`, `!~*`.

Can anyone show me an example of how they can be used?

Thanks

Comment: They're bitwise operators. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) is what they do (this is the javascript implementation).

Comment: @Brian, Really should have just posted this as an answer.

Comment: @Rock2040 just posted it. Sometimes I feel like answers that are essentially "read the docs" shouldn't be an actual answer but I suppose bitwise operators are incredibly tough to google if you don't know what they're called.

Comment: Hi @Alex, did you find either of the answers useful? If so, could you please accept one to put closure to your question? Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just like other commenters have mentioned, those are bitwise operators. PHP's bitwise operators are documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

**Examples**

`&` is a [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operator.

> A bitwise AND takes two equal-length binary representations and
>   performs the logical AND operation on each pair of the corresponding
>   bits, by multiplying them. Thus, if both bits in the compared position
>   are 1, the bit in the resulting binary representation is 1 (1 × 1 =
>   1); otherwise, the result is 0 (1 × 0 = 0 and 0 × 0 = 0)

10 & 10 = 10 (all decimal representation). How? 10 is 1010 binary.

```
    1010
and 1010
--------
    1010
```

Notice that the result is 1 only when both top and bottom number in the same column are 1.

PHP's way of writing that:

```
<?php
echo 10 & 10;
?>
Result: 10
```

What's the practical use for it? Let's take an example: There are 4 sets of double doors. Both doors have to open at the same time for a person to pass through. Open door is given number 1. Closed door is given number 2.

`1010` means first door is open, second is closed, third is open, fourth is closed. When all doors are closed, they would look like this:

```
0000  <-- first set of doors
0000  <-- second set of doors
```

To allow someone to pass through left-most door, doors should be like this:

```
0001
0001
```

That's all fine, but there's a faster way to annotate that. Bitwise operator &. We do & between both doors and get a result of 1. So if data is stored as 1, we know that left-most doors were open.

To open left-most door, the combination would have to be:

```
1000
1000
```

Result of bitwise operator is decimal 8. Use [calculator like the one on miniwebtool](http://www.miniwebtool.com/bitwise-calculator/?data_type=2&number1=1000&number2=1000&operator=AND) to run some math.

On the flip side, as the doors open and close all day, one could record when both doors of any of the 4 sets of doors were open. It's just a long-winded answer to perhaps a simple question.

Comment: They're not PHP's operators (though PHP *does* have them). They're the SQL operators.

Answer (score 4):

Posted this as a comment on the original question:

They're bitwise operators. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) is what they do (this is the javascript implementation).

Answer (score 1):

They are bitwise operators used in laravel's `where()`, method and they are supplied as oprerators, you can find more details about these opreators [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/bit-functions.html)