# laravel 5.4 bitwise operations not working as expected (Eloquent)

Tags: laravel, bitwise-operators, fluent, eloquent, bitmask

This has me stumped. I'm trying to filter `$ages=Ages::all();` based on a productmask field using bitwise operator `&`
(code should be self-explanatory)

I've tried

```
  @foreach($ages->where('productmask', '&', 2) as $option)
```

and

```
  @foreach($ages->filter(function($i){return ((int)($i->productmask & 2)); }) as $option)
```

and

```
  @foreach($ages->filter(function($i){return ((int)($i->productmask & 2) == 2); })->values() as $option)
```

and none work when productmask = 3 but do work when productmask is exactly 2.

What are my options here (no pun intended)? Why doesn't this work?

I'm pretty sure it would work if I did a `\DB::whereRaw` (because I can run this against the Db and it works and I get the 2 and 3 entries):

`SELECT * from ages WHERE productmask&2`

but here it's bypassing fluent and hitting the database inside a view?? Not good form.

Anyone using bit masks out there ever run into this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know why I had to do this exactly, but here's what i did to get it to work:

```
@foreach($locations->filter(function($i){if (decbin($i->productmask) & 16) return $i; }) as $option)
```

Basically, I had to use `decbin()` on the collection's field value (`$ages->productmask`) so that the compare would resolve correctly.

Works now! Hope this helps someone.

Comment: glad you fix this :)

Comment: once you got eligible to accept the answer pls your accept the answer to close your question

Answer (score 0):

From the [source](http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/possible-operators-on-eloquents-where-function) here suggests that

> where() takes 3 parameters, name of the column, operator and value to
>   be compared against.
>
> The operator can be one of the following: '=', '<', '>', '<=', '>=',
>   '<>', '!=', 'like', 'not like', 'between', 'ilike'

However I found something that you might need to look [here](https://packagist.org/packages/fanmade/laravel-bitwise-trait).
This will help you to fix your issues.

For further digging [see PHP documentation](http://PHP's%20bitwise%20operators%20are%20documented%20here:%20http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) also read this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743092/what-are-all-those-sql-operators-in-laravel/34125688)

and as far as your question is concerned

use your query like this

```
$ages->whereRaw('(productmask & 2)')
```

Comment: Yes I looked at that but I'd rather not have to add a new package and implement new field types just to mitigate what appears to be a simple math problem with Eloquent. Or at least with they way I'm trying to use it.

From vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php

protected $operators = [
    '=', '<', '>', '<=', '>=', '<>', '!=',
    'like', 'like binary', 'not like', 'between', 'ilike',
    '&', '|', '^', '<<', '>>',
    'rlike', 'regexp', 'not regexp',
    '~', '~*', '!~', '!~*', 'similar to',
    'not similar to',
];

Comment: i tried whereRaw. That method only seems available on the class (`Ages:whereRaw()`). I got a method not found when I tried to use it on the results of `$ages=Ages::all();`. `$ages->whereRaw()` failed.